# Is it possible to install Kali Nethunter's Apps on OxygenOS?

Tags: applications, rooting, oneplus-3, oxygenos

I just bought a OnePlus 3T. I like the OxygenOS, but I wish I had the ability to preform USB HID Attacks and use `apt-get` on OxygenOS if I don't want to install Nethunter. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Termux](https://termux.com/), a free application which allows you to access `apt-get` and many other Unix commands right on your smartphone.

You can also install the `termux-sudo` plugin, which allows you to run commands with root access.

Comment: I tried that, put their package manager isn't complete.

Comment: No, it isn't, but that's the closest you're going to get on Android. Each package has to be built and adapted for Android - the already available list is immense already.

Comment: Nethunter is actually a ROM Overlay, I'd still have OxygenOS and all the apps would be installed anyway.